# Shortcodes that are created based on user input information

Tags: shortcode

I am creating a plugin that users can create forms with. Then the user will be able to input a shortcode to display this form. The shortcode will be the form name, which is stored as a `meta_value` in the `wp_postmeta` table. When the user uses a shortcode, how do I  refer back to the form name & display the form?

When the user creates a form, should I automatically create a shortcode in the same script? How would you approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it like

```
[form id="abc123"]
```

where the value of `id` is the `meta_value`. You could generate the shortcode so the user can easily copy/paste it into the editor. Or even have a custom made button in the editor to insert it.

You can check how it's done in other plugins like `Contact Form 7`:

```
[contact-form-7 id="50" title="My form"]
```

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/screenshots/

and `Fast Secure Contact Form`:

```
[si-contact-form form='1']
```

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-contact-form/screenshots/

Comment: Thanks for helping @birgire. I'm new to wordpress & worked this out when I turned my laptop off, so must be improving. Thanks again!